# Maven - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am getting the below in Spring Boot Maven application:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/..../.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/..../.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.10.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Using below dependencies related to logging in POM.XML :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

I have tried removing those jars manually even still i am facing the issue and found some blogs on the same but those are not working for me.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file...furthermore why are you defining the version of the spring-boot-starter-log4j ?

Comment: if version not defined then getting the error so. Thanks @khmarbaise

Comment: Than I assume you have other issues in your pom ? Do you use the spring-boot-starter-parent ?

Comment: yes, please find the parent in above post. thanks @ khmarbaise

Comment: Did you solved that?